# how to run codeigniter 4 on apache2 ubuntu

Tags: 22.04, apache2, php

i work on project codeigniter 4, i installed my project on my apache2 server on ubuntu,
set my virtual host :

`127.0.0.1       du-accurate.local`

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

`127.0.1.1       X1-Cabron`

and enable my mod_rewrite

`sudo a2enmod rewrtite`

but when i access my website on local by typing du-accurate.local,
it only show part of my index.php

`systemDirectory, '\\/ ') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'bootstrap.php'; // Load environment settings from .env files into $_SERVER and $_ENV require_once SYSTEMPATH . 'Config/DotEnv.php'; (new CodeIgniter\Config\DotEnv(ROOTPATH))->load(); // Define ENVIRONMENT if (! defined('ENVIRONMENT')) { define('ENVIRONMENT', env('CI_ENVIRONMENT', 'production')); } // Load Config Cache // $factoriesCache = new \CodeIgniter\Cache\FactoriesCache(); // $factoriesCache->load('config'); // ^^^ Uncomment these lines if you want to use Config Caching. /* * --------------------------------------------------------------- * GRAB OUR CODEIGNITER INSTANCE * --------------------------------------------------------------- * * The CodeIgniter class contains the core functionality to make * the application run, and does all the dirty work to get * the pieces all working together. */ $app = Config\Services::codeigniter(); $app->initialize(); $context = is_cli() ? 'php-cli' : 'web'; $app->setContext($context); /* *--------------------------------------------------------------- * LAUNCH THE APPLICATION *--------------------------------------------------------------- * Now that everything is set up, it's time to actually fire * up the engines and make this app do its thang. */ $app->run(); // Save Config Cache // $factoriesCache->save('config'); // ^^^ Uncomment this line if you want to use Config Caching. // Exits the application, setting the exit code for CLI-based applications // that might be watching. exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`

the code above just showed on my browser as if it just text, not php code

Comment: Please format your question so it is readable.

Comment: If you have a paying client, then pay someone to help you / educate you.

Comment: ive formated my question @SorenA